# How to send bulk get requests using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I wrote a web crawler with nodejs to send get requests to about 300 urls.
Here is the main loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 300; i++) { 
    let page= `https://xxxxxxxxx/forum-103-${i}.html`
    await getPage(page,(arr)=>{
        console.log(`page ${i}`)
    })
}
```

Here is the function  getPage(url,callback):

```
export default async function getPage(url, callback) {
    await https.get(url, (res) => {
        let html = ""
        res.on("data", data => {
            html += data
        })
        res.on("end", () => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html)
            let obj = {}
            let arr = []
            obj = $("#threadlisttableid tbody")
            for (let i in obj) {
                if (obj[i].attribs?.id?.substr(0, 6) === 'normal') {
                    arr.push(`https://xxxxxxx/${obj[i].attribs.id.substr(6).split("_").join("-")}-1-1.html`)
                }
            }
            callback(arr)
            console.log("success!")
        })
    })
        .on('error', (e) => {
            console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
        })
}
```

I use cheerio to analyze HTML and put all information i need to variable nameed 'arr'.
The program will report an error after running normally for a period of time,like that:

```
...
success!
page 121
success!
page 113
success!
page 115
success!
Got error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.67.139.206:443
Got error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.67.139.206:443
Got error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.67.139.206:443
Got error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.67.139.206:443
Got error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.67.139.206:443
Got error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.67.139.206:443
```

I have two questions:

1.What is the reason for the error? Is it because I am sending too many get requests? How can I limit the request frequency?

2.As you can see, The order in which the pages are accessed is chaotic,how to control them?

I have tried using other modules to send get request (such as Axios) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http requests are fired simultaneously because the loop is not waiting for the previous request due to wrong use of `await`. Proper control of loop will limit the request frequency.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 300; i++) { 
    let page= `https://xxxxxxxxx/forum-103-${i}.html`
    var arr = await getPage(page);
    // use arr in the way you want
    console.log(`page ${i}`);
}

export default async function getPage(url) {
    // Declare a new promise, wait for the promise to resolve and return its value.
    return await new Promise((reso, rej) => {
        https.get(url, (res) => {
            let html = ""
            res.on("data", data => {
                html += data
            })
            res.on("end", () => {
                const $ = cheerio.load(html)
                let obj = {}
                let arr = []
                obj = $("#threadlisttableid tbody")
                for (let i in obj) {
                    if (obj[i].attribs?.id?.substr(0, 6) === 'normal') {
                        arr.push(`https://xxxxxxx/${obj[i].attribs.id.substr(6).split("_").join("-")}-1-1.html`)
                    }
                }
                reso(arr) // Resolve with arr
                console.log("success!")
            })
        })
        .on('error', (e) => {
            console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
            throw e;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearly specifying the cause of the error.In fact, how to get the value of `arr` has troubled me for a long time.Before, I pass in callback to operate `arr` as a last resort. Wait for the promise to return its value is a more elegant choice.But I found a little typo, is `reso(arr)` not `res(arr)`.Thank you again！

Comment: @IreneAdle reso is not a typo, it's a resolve function of the `new Promise((reso, rej)`. Glad to help you! Welcome to the stackoverflow community

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express clearly.I mean the previous line of `console.log("success!")` might be `reso(arr) //Resolve with arr` instead of `res(arr) //Resolve with arr` . ^-^

Comment: @IreneAdle woops, my bad! Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, The order in which the pages are accessed is chaotic,how to control them?

`await` is meaningless unless you put a *promise* on the right hand side. `http.get` does not deal in promises.

You could [wrap it in a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) but it would be easier to use an API which supports then natively such as [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), or [Node.js's native fetch](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v17.5.0/). (That all have APIs that are, IMO, easier to use than http.get in general nor just with regards to flow control).

> What is the reason for the error?

It isn't clear.

> Is it because I am sending too many get requests?

That is a likely hypothesis.

> How can I limit the request frequency?

Once you have your `for` loop working with promises so the requests are sent in serial instead of parallel, you can insert a [sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/19068) between each request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have found the cause of the error. As you suggested, I added sleep() to the loop and now the program works fine.